# Adding speed effects to a rect object

Tags: processing, shadow, p5.js

I have a rectangle which moves from bottom to top and repeats itself. Like so,

```javascript
var h ;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(710, 400);
    h = height;
}

function draw(){
    background(0);
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(50, h, 200, 20);

  if(h < 0){
        h = height; 
    }
    else{
        h--;    
    }

}
```

I want to have the effect which happens when any obstacles moves at a fast speed like leaving a trail for a second.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the way you'd do this is to maintain an array of previous positions and then draw those. Here's an example:

```javascript
var h;
var trail = [];

function setup(){
  createCanvas(710, 400);
    h = height;
}

function draw(){
    background(0);
  noStroke();
    fill(255,0,0);
  rect(50, h, 200, 20);

    // add to beginning of array
    trail.unshift(h);

    // chop off end of array
    if(trail.length > 10){
        trail.length = 10;
    }

    //loop over tail
    for(var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++){
        // you can do stuff like set the opacity based on the index
        fill(255, 0, 0, 100-i*5);
        // you can also set the position and width based on the index
        rect(50+i*10, trail[i], 200-i*20, 20);  
    }

  if(h < 0){
        h = height; 
    }
    else{
        h-=5;    
    }
}
```

You'll have to play with it a little bit to get the effect you're going for, but the basic idea is the same: just use an array to hold previous positions, and then draw them to create your trail.

Answer (score 0):

You can get interesting effects by replacing `background(0)` in draw by a full-window rectangle which is partially transparent. For example:

```
function draw(){
  fill(0,20); //experiment with other alpha values
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(50, h, 200, 20);

  if(h < 0){
        h = height; 
    }
    else{
        h -=3; //experiment with different speeds  
    }
```

The moving rectangles will leave a trail of partially visible rectangles behind it.

Answer (score 0):

do as you were but each frame, in the draw() function:

```
background(0, 100);
```

this sets the background with an opacity... it will work. trust me